# how to display the tamil content website in default browser

Tags: android

how to show tamil language  characters in android ,i have simple webview apllication ,it loads the url of tamil news site which contains tamil characters ,but its showing [][][][ at place of those characters ,even the default android browser shows the same (not showing the hindi or tamil characters ) the android version is 2.1, text encoding is set on unicode(UTF-8) in default android browser .,is there is any way to get the support for tamil characters i hope my question is clear ,

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do not have language pack of tamil installed in your current os. Further you are even on old operating system 'froyo' which is not much supported now a days that is 2.1

Kindly find measure to officially update your device to atleast Gingerbread which is 2.3.x and find tamil language pack for it. Once you are update with the language pack you will find characters displaying on your device no matter on which state of interface you are.

Answer (score 0):

Install Sith Browser which will support Tamil [Sith Browser for Tamil web sites](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sithagi.sithbrowser) or [Sith Browser](http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2013/12/sith-browser.html)